# New function in another new function

Tags: javascript

Problem solved: (http://jsfiddle.net/336e6pbh/15/) (Solution).

I have this simple js code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/336e6pbh/4/) (jsFiddle link).

```
Desktop();
GalleryButton();

function Desktop() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var footer = document.createElement("footer");
    var content = document.createElement("div");

    wrapper.appendChild(content);
    content.appendChild(footer);

    footer.id = "mainFooter";
    content.id = "content";
}

function GalleryButton() {
    var galleryImg = document.createElement("img");
    var galleryButton = document.createElement("a");
    galleryButton.setAttribute("href", "#");
    galleryImg.setAttribute("src", "pics/gallery.png");

    var bottom = document.getElementById("mainFooter");
    galleryButton.appendChild(galleryImg);
    bottom.appendChild(galleryButton);

    galleryButton.onclick = function () {
        new NewBox();
    };
}

function NewWindow() {
    var popup = document.createElement("div");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");

    popup.id = "popup";
    content.appendChild(popup);
}

function NewBox() {
    new NewWindow();
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    var content = document.getElementById("popup");

    box.id = "box";
    popup.appendChild(box);
}
```

When I click the img in the left corner a new popup shows with a yellow box inside.
My question is how do I get a new popup with a new yellow box in the new popup?

I could put the code from NewWindow to NewBox function but I want these functions separate.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: the correct fiddle is THIS one: http://jsfiddle.net/336e6pbh/4/, he edited it slightly BEFORE you edited it ;)

Comment: @briosheje I relized so I did the rollback.

Comment: if you check the source code. your new blue box div does not contain div with id box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second call to document.getElementById("popup"); is finding the first div with id=popup and putting the yellow box in there.

Your element IDs should be unique :[HTML SPEC](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: You are right. Do you know another way for getElementById?

Comment: Don't assign elements the same ID, maybe assign them a certain class and then something like var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names). Or create a unique ID each time? count the popup* divs and create a popup div with id=popup[count+1] ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle, I have changed your code and your CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/336e6pbh/5/

```
function GalleryButton() {
var galleryImg = document.createElement("img");
var galleryButton = document.createElement("a");
galleryButton.setAttribute("href", "#");
galleryImg.setAttribute("src", "pics/gallery.png");

var bottom = document.getElementById("mainFooter");
galleryButton.appendChild(galleryImg);
bottom.appendChild(galleryButton);

galleryButton.onclick = function () {
    new newPopUp();
};
}

function newPopUp(){
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var popup = document.createElement("div");
popup.className = "popup";
var blueBox = document.createElement("div");
blueBox.className = "blueBox";

popup.appendChild(blueBox);

content.appendChild(popup);    
 }
```

your CSS will be like this

```
#content {
background-color: #ccc;
height:300px;
width:350px;
}
#mainFooter {
border:1px solid #000;
height:50px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.popup {
background-color: blue;
border:1px solid pink;
height:100px;
width:150px;
}
.blueBox {
background-color: yellow;
height:20px;
width:40px;
}
```

your HTML code will be as it is....

Comment: Thanks but i need NewWindow as it is so i can call it several times